# Remove leading 0 from Rails Form Helper select_hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`select_hour` renders 7 AM as 07 AM because apparently Rails devs have never used a clock in the real world, and it looks terrible to end users. Is there any way to remove the leading 0?

Answer (score 1):

Docs say this should work: `select_hour(use_two_digit_numbers: false)`

See: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/DateTimeSelector/build_options

Comment: I'll give this another try tomorrow, but I can't get it to work with that option yet; it seems logical though.